# mod_wsgi + cherrypy = 404 - The path '/index.wsgi/' was not found

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, cherrypy

**The .htaccess :**

```
AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(media/.*)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.wsgi/$1 [QSA,L,PT]
```

**The index.wsgi :**

```
import atexit
import threading
import cherrypy

cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})

if cherrypy.engine.state == 0:
        cherrypy.engine.start(blocking=False)
        atexit.register(cherrypy.engine.stop)

class Root:
        def index(self):
            return "..."
            index.exposed = True

    def default(self):
            return "default"
                index.exposed = True

application = cherrypy.tree.mount(Root(), "/")
```

- **It is a shared host, i don't have access to apache**
- **I'm not allowed to use WSGIScriptAlias**

The 404 error comes from cherrypy(powered by cherrypy on the botton), so i conclude apache is calling the .wsgi file correctly, it seems that its also passing /index.wsgi/, and cherrypy does not know what to do with it.

**Can anyone help me with this?**

I never deployed a cherrypy app before, is this the best/only/recommended way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting RewriteBase to '/' in .htaccess, likely that you need to use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.wsgi$1 [QSA,L,PT]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, still Cherrypy outputs : 404 - The path '/index.wsgi' was not found. Any ideas?

Comment: See 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive'. You need to use a WSGI wrapper script to fiddle SCRIPT_NAME when you are using the rewrite rule method. Didn't catch you weren't doing this before. If that recipe has a problem now with missing slash, you may need to put it back in rewrite rule or otherwise will need to fiddle with it a bit to get it to work as example is not for .htaccess file.

Comment: That was it, i had to set SCRIPT_NAME to "", that solved, tnx for the help, Jim.

Comment: Did you still need to drop the '/' out of the RewriteRule, or were both changes required?

Comment: It worked with the .htaccess as it is in the post, the only change i made was setting environ["SCRIPT_NAME"] = "", my database connections died though (http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Storm) apparently mod_wsgi handles threads differently, do you happen to know if there's another event where i could hook the connection?Tnx in advance.

Comment: The mod_wsgi package doesn't do any thing out of the ordinary with threads. A Python application should see them the same as if run under pure Python WSGI server. Do however read 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading'. If you are running multithread configuration and the software you are using is not thread safe you will have issues. You could also be having issues with multiprocess configuration.